# What does Vout-pp mean?

Tags: power-supply

When looking at the Texas Instruments Webench designer, one of the columns reads

> Vout-pp

What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: It's a little bit hard to tell without more context, but usually `pp` stands for peak-to-peak.  Does this fit your context?

Comment: This is to do with buck converters, so I'm wondering if it's to do with dropout voltage or voltage ripple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Output Ripple Voltage*, peak to peak.

This is the expected ripple the proposed design would produce, at the rated parameters of operation. **Less is better**, all else being equal.